# Jquery .each() not adding sums

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have this code that I'm trying to get it to add up all the sums plus there quantities. How it works now it only adds one of the items. What am i missing?

```
function addSubTotal() {
var subTotal = 0;
var total = 0;

    $("#items").find("#itemadd").each(function() {
        var qty = parseInt($(this).find("#qty").val());
        var rate = parseInt($(this).find("#price").html());
        subTotal += qty * rate; 
    });
        $("#subTotal").html(subTotal);
  }
```

and this is the code i use to dynamically add it

```
function addItem(a, b) {
$("#items").append("<div id=itemadd> <span id=remove>remove</span> <span id=item>" + a + "</span> <input id=qty type=number autocomplete=off value=2> <span id=price>" + b + "</span></div>");
addSubTotal();
}
```

Comment: IDs must be _unique_.

Comment: use a class instead of ID for repeated elements.

Comment: OMG it was that simple... Thought i was losing my mind... damn IDs... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using the `id` attribute. An `id` *must* be unique. Otherwise, the browser will only return the first instance of an element with that id that it finds.

You want to make these classes instead, then search for `.itemadd`.

Check out this quick example:
https://jsfiddle.net/2b7zfjha/

Comment: OMG it was that simple... Thought i was losing my mind... damn IDs... Thank you!